# Graphing hr on X axis in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Please help me.
I looked for the way to graph the following table and I could not.
Take the column "HR" for the X axis and "VALUE" for Y axis, the problem is that the graph is cut. Column "RNO" only for sort.
For example: the value  graph X Axis 10,11, ..., 21,22,23 when reaching the value or 00 does not continue the graph in the X axis, what happens is that values less than 10 puts them first. I attach the image that appears to me:

HR RATE_TIMEWAITED_PER_CLASS        RNO

---

11                                    1
12                135.083333          2
13                232.916667          3
14                130.611111          4
15                155.111111          5
16                186.472222          6
17                166.805556          7
18                110.916667          8
19                89.3055556          9
20                198.166667         10
21                56.0277778         11
22                32.0277778         12
23                29.4722222         13
00                501.111111         14
01                18.6944444         15
02                16.0555556         16
03                14.1666667         17
04                375.892811         18
05                16.0833333         19
06                29.8611111         20
07                79.6666667         21
08                    131.25         22
09                332.666667         23

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1gSZ.jpg

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example